# Junit - Spring boot: @Value is always null while testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, context-configuration

There is a @Value annotated constant, which is not getting initialized when running test, it throws NullPointerException when it is required inside constructor.

Sample Class to be tested:

```java
class TestClass {
    @Value("${test.value1}")
    private String value1;

    private final TestTemplate testTemplate;

    public TestClass(TestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        testTemplate = builder.someMethod(value1).build();
    }


    ---
}
```

Sample Test Class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestClass.class)
@SpringBootTest
class TestClassTest {

    @MockBean
    TestTemplateBuilder builder;

    @Autowired
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass(testTemplate);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(testClass, "value1", "VALUE");

        Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(new TestTemplate());
    }

    ---
}
```

Things tried, but nothing worked:

- I have created `application.properties` file with required value.
- Created `application-test.properties` and added `@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")`.
- `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "test.value1=VALUE" })`

I have tried some other things also, but what i got is `NullPoiterException` at `someMethod(value1)`.

Versions:

- Java: 1.8
- Springboot: 2.1.17
- Junit: 4.12
- Mockito: 2.23.4

Comment: What can I say… ditch Mockito and use Spock instead, then add the @SpringBootTest annotation and you get a full testing container for free.

Comment: You are creating an aninstance of `TestClass` yourself. It has nothing injected or processed. Remove the `new TestClass` to init the field. Also you should register behavior but you are already calling the mock in the constructor so this will be impossible. What you should do is don't use Spring for this test, create the mock and instances yourself and run the tests. You don't have to use Spring for everything especially if you want to write a simple unit test.

Comment: @M.Deinum i got the point of removing unnecessary things. Could you share a sample or some link which help me understand.

Answer (score 2):

If @Before is not working, then try with @BeforeEach. It worked for me.

```
`@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(yourInstanceClass, "fieldName", "fieldValue");
}`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure (because in the question, it's doesn't showed):
class `TestClass` is `Spring bean` (Component, Service...)?

Edit (*`TestClass` is Component*):

This is not how `Spring bean` are created;

If constructor of `TestClass` require @Value then only Spring will guarantee that before instantiating `TestClass` the `test.value1` value is available.
So you can add to the constructor  `@Value("${test.value1}")String value1` and set the `value1` property.

Please read the ways of how `Spring` inject.

Comment: It is a `Component`.

Comment: I got the points stated by you, so the issue is with `TestClass`. I didn't write the `TestClass` so i cannot change now but will change in future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting NullPointerException is that the value injection occurs after the constructor call. To prevent this you can use spring life cycle hooks to initialize your class after the constructor call.

Comment: `value1` is used inside constructor so it's value should have been initialized before constructor call. As you say **value injection occurs after the constructor call** can you back this by some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the main issue, but i fulfilled my requirement like this.

```java
class TestClassTest {

    TestClass testClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        TestTemplateBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(TestTemplateBuilder.clsss);

        TestTemplateBuilder builder1 = Mockito.mock(TestTemplateBuilder.clsss);

        Mockito.when(builder.someMethod(nullable(String.class))).thenReturn(builder1);

        Mockito.when(builder1.build()).thenReturn(new TestTemplate());

        testClass = new TestClass(builder);
    }

    ---
}
```

This might not be the correct way of doing.